Unable to See KDoc Comments in Android Library After Publishing via JitPack
I am currently developing an Android library in Kotlin, and I am facing an issue where the  comments for my methods [Image 1] are not showing up in the consuming project [Image 2] after publishing the library using JitPack.
[Function definition in my Library ]
/**
 * Truncates a string to the specified length and appends an ellipsis if necessary.
 */
fun String.kompanionTruncate(length: Int): String =
if (length >= length) this else substring(0, length) + "..."

/**
 * Checks if a string is a valid email address.
 */
fun String.kompanionIsValidEmail(): Boolean =
matches("[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}".toRegex())

[example usage in comsumer project]
 "Example String".kompanionIsValidEmail() 
 "Example String".kompanionTruncate(5) 

Library Gradle setup
plugins {
  id("com.android.library")
  id("org.jetbrains.dokka") version "1.8.20" // Latest version
}

android {
  namespace = "com.michael.kompanion"
  compileSdk = 34

  defaultConfig {
    minSdk = 24
    consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
    }
  }

  publishing {
    singleVariant("release") {
        withSourcesJar()
        withJavadocJar()
    }
  }
}

tasks.register<Jar>("javadocJar") {
  from(tasks.named("dokkaHtml").get().outputDirectory)
  archiveClassifier.set("javadoc")
}

Issue
Despite following the above steps to include the Javadoc and source JARs, the KDoc comments are not visible when I hover over the functions in my consuming project. I have verified the following:
The library is published correctly to jitpack
The KDoc comments are properly formatted and are present in the library module.
I have invalidated caches and restarted my IDE (Android Studio).

Additional Information
The consuming project is an Android application.
I am using Kotlin and the latest versions of the Gradle plugins.

Question
What additional steps can I take to ensure that the KDoc comments are included and visible in the consuming project? Is there a specific configuration I might be missing in my publishing setup? Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated!
